# CssResource @Source annotation when using @external

Tags: gwt

What happens when using multiple in the @Source annotation of a CssResource in a ClientBundle? Is this compatible with using @External/@CssResource.NotStrict?

To be more specific - in our codebase I encountered a ClientBundle that contains something like this:

```
@Source({"style1.css", style2.css"})
@CssResource.NotStrict
CustomCss css();
```

This suggests that definitions in style2 can override definitions in style1. Should this also work when using @CssResource.NotStrict, so without the accessors and obfuscation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `@Source` has multiple values, it's equivalent to concatenating the files (in order) into a big stylesheet. This is mostly useful to import constants (`@def`, `@eval` or `@url`) or `@external`s.

It doesn't change anything to the behavior or `@external` (note: that means one file can declare as `@external` a class name used in another file) or `@NotStrict`.